# Pass props to a mapped array of different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of imported React components with different names, and I'd like to iterate over them and pass the same props to each of them, but I can't find a way to do this properly.

Here's what I have in a form of pseudocode:

```
const myArray = [
  <Component1 />,
  <Component2 />,
  <Component3 />,
];

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {myArray.map( ComponentX => {ComponentX} )} // pass the same props into these components?
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: If I understand it right, you want to pass some new prop to each element in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use JSX inside the array and you should be good:

```js
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.prop}</div>;
  }
}

class Component2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.prop}</div>;
  }
}

const myArray = [
  Component1,
  Component2,
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {myArray.map(ComponentX => <ComponentX prop="Hello World!" /> )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly the style I was looking for! 

Apparently, one has to be careful with naming this "ComponentX": in the actual component I was building, the components were "Line1, Line2, etc." and I called the mapped component LineX, which generated lots of errors and a list of <linex></linex> tags ! However, with "ComponentX" it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [`React.cloneElement()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

```
render() {
    const myArray = [
        <Component1 />,
        <Component2 />,
        <Component3 />,
    ];
    const extraProps = {
        foo: 'bar'
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {myArray.map(comp => React.cloneElement(comp, extraProps))}
        </div>
    );
}
```